# Remove onmouseover event from DOM elements efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onmouseover

I have an HTML page that contains many onmouseover events. These events are linked to a,img,td and div tags.

What is the most efficient Javascript way to remove all the onmouseover events, presuming the page has loaded.

I'm not using jQuery.

(the task is to remove unneeded tooltips when the page is accessed using touch devices)

Comment: Are all `onmouseover` pointing to the same central function to display tooltips?

Comment: Yes, but I can't disable the tooltip, because it is used in some onclick events.

Comment: Have you actually verified that this requires optimization? What is the current lag time in removing the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a unique class to everything that has the mouseover event and then make a loop

```
get=document.getElementsByClassName("classhere");
for(i=0; i<get.length; i++){
    get[i].removeEventListener("mouseover", yourFunction, false);
   }
```

replace `yourFunction` and `classhere`, tell me if it works or not

Comment: This solution is quick and efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since all your event handlers point to the same central function - you *can* disable tooltips inside of that function.

If this function handles both `onmouseover` and `onclick` events - you can check `event.type` and disable tooltips only if it's equal `mouseover.`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cLHgK/1/

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to remove the onmouseover events, as the iPhone is capturing them when trying to click on element, and processing them incorrectly. The only solution is to remove them entirely.

Comment: Really? Even if your code specifically states to do nothing on mouseover  and just return? Weird.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function looping through all the elements should do the trick. This one does it for all divs:-

```
function removeMouseOver() {
    var divs = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].onmoseover = function() {};
    }
}
```

another way is to define the mouseover tooltip function as a var

```
var tooltip = function(){// put your tooltip code here };
var donothing = function(){};

//to turn tooltips on:-
onmouseoverfunc = tooltip;

//to turn tooltips off:-
onmouseoverfunc = donothing;
```

in the elements

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').onmouseover = function(){mouseoverfunc();};
```

Comment: Your answer is the most complete, but the other answer is the one that I used!